# How to change ListBox Height property?

Tags: excel, vba

When I debug (pressing **F8**), the height of the listbox changes according to the code.

When I run the code using **F5**, the height is ajusted to 1 list member height.

I tried using `.IntegralHeight=True` in the end also, that's why it is a comment in the code.

*Ps.: I ran the code using Variable Inspection, and until the `Opções_povoar` sub ends, the `.Height` property stands at 200*

UserForm Properties

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call Opções_povoar

End Sub

Private Sub Opções_povoar()

Dim arr As Variant, i As Long
arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

With UserForm1.ListBox1
    .List = arr
    Debug.Print .ListCount
    .ListIndex = -1
    .ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
    .Font.Size = 20
    .Top = 50
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .Height = 200 '.Font.Size * .ListCount
    '.IntegralHeight = True

    Debug.Print .Height
    '****ajustar automaticamente a altura da lista

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: please try to move line: `.Font.Size = 20` after line: `.Height = 200 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change

```
With UserForm1.ListBox1
```

to

```
With Me.ListBox1
```

`Me` is the keyword referring to the instance of the userform  object to which the code is inside to

while `Userform1` is pointing at the class

so that part of code should be:

```
With Me.ListBox1
    .List = arr
    Debug.Print .ListCount
    .ListIndex = -1
    .ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
    .Font.Size = 20
    .Top = 50
    .IntegralHeight = False

    Debug.Print .Height ' <--- this prints 39,55

    .Height = 400

    Debug.Print .Height ' <--- this prints 400

End With
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, but it didn't work. The listbox showed the same behavior.

Comment: It worked for me. Using `With Userform1.Listbox1` it didn't change listbox height, while using `With Me.Listbox1` did change it (see edited answer)

Comment: I'm sorry but I own you apologies. I was calling this code in `UserForm_Initialize()`, when I as supposed to do in `UserForm_Activate()`. Worked as expected now. Thank you for the suppport.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to give the userform time to catch up with the code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Call Opções_povoar

End Sub

Private Sub Opções_povoar()

    Dim arr As Variant, i As Long
    arr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .List = arr
        Debug.Print .ListCount
        .ListIndex = -1
        .ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
        .Font.Size = 20
        .Top = 50
        .IntegralHeight = False
        '--------------------------------
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        '----------------------------------
        .Height = 200                            '.Font.Size * .ListCount
        '.IntegralHeight = True


        Debug.Print .Height
        '****ajustar automaticamente a altura da lista

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: The form worked as expected. But it seems like a workaround. Is this a normal behavior? Because I googled for at least 4 hours and tested many possibilities, but nothing worked.

Comment: Sorry, but I made a begginers mistake. See answer below. Thank you for your support.